# Scheme: What type is read?

Tags: syntax, types, functional-programming, scheme

When I read from user input from the console in scheme, what is the type that I need to use if i'm converting from that type into something I want?

For example
(string->number "20") converts the string into a number, what is the syntax for this regarding a read?

FOR EXAMPLE

```
(define input(read)
    (let ((r read))
    (????->number r)))
```

Comment: Are you passing a value that was read to `input` or the function `read`? Because nowhere in `input` do you read a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the Racket documentation for `read` we see as signature : `(read [in]) → any`.

So in your case if the user inputs a number it will return a number.
But explicitly check that it is a number because you can't be sure the user won't input something else!

An example :

```
(define (read-number)
    (let ((inpt (read)))
      (if (number? inpt)
          inpt
          (begin (display "Please input a number!")
                 (newline)
                 (read-number)))))
```

EDIT : If you want to test if the inputted number was zero, you should replace the `if`-statement by a conditional.

```
(cond ((and (number? inpt)
            (= inpt 0)) ; Works because of lazy evalutation
       ; User inputted 0
       ...)
      ((number? inpt) 
       ; User inputted a number other then zero
       ...)
      (else
       ; User did not entered a number!
       (display "Please input a number!")
       (newline)
       (read-number)))
```

Comment: Instead of checking for a number you check for a zero instead on line 3, i'm attempting to do that but i'm getting an error where it expects a number but gets a type of #<subr read> which I can only assume is casting the inpt before read is even applied?

Comment: So to get the straight, the inpt isn't casted right away when it's being set? If there is a call to compare it with something from a read it has to check what type it is beforehand, or is that just good practice?

Comment: @James We first have to check that it is a number else `(= inpt 0)` will raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

`read` doesn't return anything of a specific type – it reads the textual representation of a Scheme object and returns such an object.

Example (input indicated with `<-`) :

```
> (read)
<- 23
23
> (read)
<- "hello"
"hello"
> (read)
<- (1 2 3)
'(1 2 3)
> (number? (read))
<- 23
#t
> (number? (read))
<- "hello"
#f
> (define x (read))
<- 4
> x
4
> (number? x)
#t
> (eqv? x 4)
#t
> (+ x 1)
5
> (let ((y (read))) (* y 2))
<- 4
8
```

So if you want a number, and the user inputs a number, you don't need to do anything.
You may want to check that the input actually is a number and ask for a new value in that case, though.

Comment: Then how does using that read for a let work?

so lets say I do this
read -> 4
(let (r read))

is r set to 4 as a number or what?

Comment: @James Yes, since the result of `(read)` would be the number 4 (I added some interactions). But don't forget the parentheses.